# Upgrading to Webpack 5 - TypeError: Cannot read property 'mkdir' of undefined

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I am currently migrating from webpack v4 to v5 and I am spinning up my dev environment and I get

```
/../../../web/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/fs.js:200
    fs.mkdir(p, err => {
       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mkdir' of undefined
    at mkdirp (/../../../web/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/fs.js:200:5)
    at /../../../web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:853:4
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/../../../web/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/../../../web/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.emitAssets (/../../../web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:850:19)
    at /../../../web/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:438:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

I have tried upgrading/downgrading all my packages to current versions as well as upgrading node from v14 to v15 and still hitting this error. I have tried previous versions of `webpack@5` and `webpack-cli`. I have also `rm -rf node_modules` & `yarn.lock`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I have an express server setup with a `server.js` file and in webpack 4 I needed `serverCompiler.outputFileSystem = devMiddleware.fileSystem;` in `server.js` for my dev environment. I no longer need this in webpack 5, so simply deleting this line fixes the error.